# Deleting a child record when deleting the parent record

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have been trying to use the `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` but it seems not to work.

My database is hosted on phpmyadmin.com. The queries I used to create the tables were:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Workers (ID_Dip char(15) PRIMARY KEY,Nome Char(20) NOT NULL,Cognome char (20) NOT NULL,DataN Date NOT NULL,Category char(10) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User (userID char(20) PRIMARY KEY,pass Char(20) NOT   NULL,ID_Worker char(15) References Worker(ID_Dip) On Delete Cascade On Update Cascade);

INSERT INTO `Workers`(`ID_Dip`, `Nome`, `Cognome`, `DataN`, `Category`) VALUES ("AV690V","myname","mysurname","1993-11-07","admin");
INSERT INTO `User`(`UserID`, `pass`, `ID_Worker`) VALUES ("myUserName","123","AV690V");
```

The problem is that when I delete the record where `ID = AV690V` in the `Workers` table, the corresponding record in the `User` table doesn't delete automatically (which it should happen automatically because of `ON DELETE CASCADE`).

How can I delete a child record when deleting the parent record?

Comment: Which storage engine does your table use?

Answer (score 0):

from http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

> Notice that ON DELETE CASCADE works only with tables whose storage
>   engines support foreign keys e.g., InnoDB. Some table types do not
>   support foreign keys such as MyISAM so you should choose appropriate
>   storage engines for the tables that you plan to use the MySQL ON
>   DELETE CASCADE referential action.

So, rethorical question: Which storage engine does your table use? :)

Comment: i am not sure ..
my db is hosted on PHPMYADMIN.co

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html):

> MySQL does not recognize or support “inline `REFERENCES` specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts `REFERENCES` clauses only when specified as part of a separate `FOREIGN KEY` specification.

You should define the foreign key explicitly:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
       User
       (
       userID char(20) PRIMARY KEY,
       pass Char(20) NOT NULL,
       ID_Worker char(15),
       FOREIGN KEY
               fk_user_worker (id_worker)
       REFERENCES
               Worker (ID_Dip)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
       )
```

Comment: ill try to do in this way and inform.
anyway can you explain "fk_user_worker " ? what does that mean ? is that an alias or a specific comand ?

Comment: @HaiderAli: it's the foreign key name. You can omit it.